# GraphQl cannot find symbol mashaller()

Tags: android, graphql

Here's my query. I'm getting this error and haven't been able to find anything close to a solution. I'm using Apollo GraphQl version 1.0.1

writer.writeObject($responseFields[27], writer != null ? writer.marshaller() : null);
                                                               ^

symbol:   method marshaller()

location: variable writer of type ResponseWriter

```
query TodayVerseQuery {
    devotion {
        apply
        applyHtml
        applyLabel
        article
        articleHtml
        articleSummary
        articleSummaryHtml
        date
        id
        pray
        prayHtml
        prayLabel
        readRef
        scriptureUrl
        status
        streamUrl
        title
        url
        verse
        verseReference
        votdMobile
        votdMobileAlt
        votdSocial
        votdSocialAlt
        votdTablet
        votdTabletAlt
        writer {
          id
          writerName
          writerBio
          writerBioHtml
          writerPhoto
          writerTitle
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue. Near the bottom I originally had an object named `writer`, which as you can see shares a name with `ResponseWriter writer`. So I used an alias and changed my object from `writer` to `theWriter`.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ResponseFieldMarshaller marshaller() {
      return new ResponseFieldMarshaller() {
        @Override
        public void marshal(ResponseWriter writer) {
          writer.writeString($responseFields[0], __typename);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[1], apply);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[2], applyHtml);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[3], applyLabel);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[4], article);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[5], articleHtml);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[6], articleSummary);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[7], articleSummaryHtml);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[8], date);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[9], id);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[10], pray);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[11], prayHtml);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[12], prayLabel);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[13], readRef);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[14], scriptureUrl);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[15], status);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[16], streamUrl);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[17], title);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[18], url);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[19], verse);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[20], verseReference);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[21], votdMobile);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[22], votdMobileAlt);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[23], votdSocial);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[24], votdSocialAlt);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[25], votdTablet);
          writer.writeString($responseFields[26], votdTabletAlt);
          writer.writeObject($responseFields[27], theWriter != null ? theWriter.marshaller() : null);
        }
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like @MrBovineJoni, I had the same error. In my case I had attribute called "writer" in  my schema. Probably this name has to be avoided while writing a schema.

Changing attribute name to "thewriter" solved the problem in my case.